# NSRangeException error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am obj c n00b so forgive me if this is a dumb question, but my app is crashing when this JSON call is happening and it wasn't before. I am 95% positive it has something to do with the php call on the server. Would love any thoughts on this. :)

Thanks!

Here is where it breaks...

```
else if([ret_st hasPrefix:@"Account veri"]){


    NSMutableArray *Array=[ret_st componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
    appDelegate.user_id=[Array objectAtIndex:1];
```

NSLog(@"user_id %@",appDelegate.user_id);

2012-04-07 09:43:51.094 App[57919:15e03] request requestType=signup&name=Test&email=test@test.com&password=test&zip=90084&id=22   return_strr Account verified204
    2012-04-07 09:43:51.094 App[57919:15e03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x1a23022 0x1e0ccd6 0x1a0f644 0xdb5d 0x10a85d 0x19f7936 0x19f73d7 0x195a790 0x1959d84 0x1959c9b 0x230d7d8 0x230d88a 0x442626 0x279d 0x2065)
    terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: It would help if we had a code sample of where you think this exception is occurring. Using `NSLog`s can help you narrow it down.

Comment: So `Array` has no objects in it, and accessing index 1 results in this exception.

Comment: So does that mean I need to change the return string or something? Because from the JSON call it gets the Account verified204?

Comment: Log the contents of `ret_st` to see what it actually returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere you have an array with one object in it at index 0 (bounds [0 .. 0]) but you are asking for an object at index 1 (index 1 beyond bounds).  Check your code for `objectAtIndex:` calls.

Comment: It breaks right here:  NSMutableArray *Array=[ret_st componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
  appDelegate.user_id=[Array objectAtIndex:1]; Do I need to change the objectAtIndex?

Comment: Yes, @MaxRoper.  NSLog that string before you separate into components.  I'm certain you'll find that it has no underscores.  When it breaks into just one string (itself), you'll have an array whose max index is 0.  Index 1 is out of bounds.

Comment: It's not only about the index but also about the program logic.  The way I read it, you have a case where `ret_st` doesn't match what you expect it to be.  You need to ask yourself what you want to do about that.  Also, `componentsSeparatedByString:` returns NSArray, not NSMutableArray.

Comment: Thanks so much! The only weird thing with this is that the app is going live Tuesday and that wont be enough time to get the update in with Apple. If I add a _ to the return string would that work?

Comment: I **think** that a trailing _ will put an empty string into your array as the second component (index 1) which should mask the immediate problem.  (You'd have to try it to be sure.)  What that will do to the rest of your program is anybody's guess.